# Firefox 13.0.1 css positioning issues

Tags: css, firefox, positioning

I have never run into this kind of thing before. Every browser renders everything perfect including IE7&8 except for Firefox (using 13.0.1).

All of the central content appears to be shifted upwards in Firefox, the header and the footer are placed correctly. Also the bottom UPC image appears to be displayed in both a scaled version and an duplicated unscaled version.

If anyone knows of a reason why Firefox would shift everything up but not a single other tested browser. I am used to having problems in IE but not Firefox.

The html is at mpact-media.com/index_new.html

Thank you all for your time and consideration.

I have included screenshots below. Ok so I have not included them, as new users aren't allowed to post images. So, the page displays correctly in Safari, Chrome, Opera, IE7, IE8 and IE9.

Firefox Screenshot

Safari/Chrome Screenshot

Opera Screenshot

IE8 Screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `position: relative;` to `position: absolute;` on `#content`:

```
#content {
    display: table-cell;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    top: 170px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 896px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Seybsen. I would have sworn I had tried that. Apparently not though. I really appreciate you taking a look at it. Thank you.